# Meteor URL prefix

Tags: meteor, underscore.js

I have an issue with Meteor 0.6.6.2

When I deploy on the production. I have to following error :

```
/home/gt/webapps/meteor/bundle/programs/server/boot.js:185
}).run();
   ^
Error: a route URL prefix must begin with a slash
    at _.extend.declare (packages/routepolicy/routepolicy.js:95)
    at new StreamServer (packages/livedata/stream_server.js:23)
    at new Server (packages/livedata/livedata_server.js:980)
    at Package (packages/livedata/server_convenience.js:10)
    at packages/livedata.js:3909:4
    at packages/livedata.js:3920:3
    at /home/gt/webapps/meteor/bundle/programs/server/boot.js:154:10
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Function._.each._.forEach (/home/gt/webapps/meteor/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
    at /home/gt/webapps/meteor/bundle/programs/server/boot.js:81:5
```

My root_url is set to :

export ROOT_URL='http://sub.mydomain.com'

I had not problem with older version of Meteor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the error.  I debugged the paths in routepolicy.js ( in /bundle/programs/server/app
line 56 with console.info(urlPrefix) ) and found that my export ROOT_URL was not correct.
For some reason, my export command (export ROOT_URL='http://mydomain.com' was not successfull and it was still ROOT_URL='mydomain.com')

See :
Github issue : https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/1404

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I'm doing to support namespaced routes (using Iron Router):

`lib/namespace.js` contains:

```
Router._mapOld = Router.map;

Router.map = function(namespace, cb) {
    if (_.isFunction(namespace)) {
        cb = namespace;
        return Router._mapOld.call(this, cb);
    }

    namespace = namespace.replace(/\/+$/, '');

    var that       = this;
    that._routeOld = that.route;
    that.route     = function(name, options) {
        if (!_.isString(options.path)) {
            throw new Error(
                'Namespaced routes must have a path specified as a string.');
        }
        return that._routeOld.call(that, name, _.extend(options, {
            path : namespace + options.path
        }));
    };

    var ret = Router._mapOld.call(that, cb);

    that.route = that._routeOld;

    return ret;
};
```

Then you can do:

```
Router.map(function() {
    // Add routes normally with no prefix
});

Router.map('/prefix', function() {
    // All routes you add here will be prefixed with /prefix
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you use middleware, or server side routes somewhere? If so, all `path` params for middleware must begin with a `/`, so change `some/path` to `/some/path`. It started to be important in one of recent versions.

`ROOT_URL` does not have to end with a `/`, by the way – yours is correct.

Comment: Is there a way for me to debug and find out where the error comes from ?

Comment: @gpasse Do you have any packages or something that you make server side routes with? Such as iron-router or meteor router?

Comment: I don't know how to pinpoint the error. However, searching your server code and packages for `WebApp.connectHandlers` and `WebApp.stack` will probably result in all possible places.

Comment: @Tarang I tired all major routers for Meteor, the most succesfull has been Backbone router.

Comment: @gpasse isn't this issue due to a server side route? I thought Backbone is meant only for client side routes

Comment: @Tarang The issue was wrong ROOT_URL parameter and actually the error message was not clear enough. But that will be fixed soon.